# difference between hibernate.show_sql & spring.jpa.show_sql?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I couldn't find any question which clearly explains about exact differences between **hibernate.show_sql** and **spring.jpa.show_sql**. That's why I am posting this question. Could you please anyone explain to me what are the differences between these two and when to use what?

As I know, when an application doesn't support spring & JPA and they are using only Hibernate, there is the only possible to use hibernate.show_sql. When an application supports Spring & JPA it's better to use spring.jpa.show_sql and no need of specifying the hibernate.show_sql. Correct me if something wrong in my understanding?

I have seen an application where both of these are configured in the **application.properties**, that's where I got the doubt.

Comment: There isn't. `spring.jpa.show_sql` is a Spring Boot property to enable logging. The other property is the hibernate specific one which will ultimatly be set through Spring Boot.

Comment: then no need to specifying hibernate.show_sql?

Comment: No you don't. An generally in a non-spring boot app, you can configure SQL logging by setting the `showSql` property to `true` on the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`.

Answer (score 2):

hibernate.show_sql and spring.jpa.show_sql result in the same if you are using Hibernate and uses a Hibernate interal logging mechanism to print the SQL statements.

spring.jpa.show_sql is just a generic property that would work with any JPA implementations.

But I prefer using a Logging Framework to print the SQL statements.

In Spring Boot you can achieve this by setting these loggers:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

The second line also prints the bind variables.

These levels also work with non Spring Boot applications. For example if you use Hibernate standalone simply add Log4J and a Log4J configuration.

Comment: Yes, @simon your suggestion to use logging level to DEBUG and TRACE is useful, one can easily execute the SQL as and when needed.